# Share dynamic content on LinkedIn

Tags: dynamic, linkedin-api

I have a JS based CMS that populates a single page with different content based on URL parameters passed to the page. I am using the shareURL format (https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=''&title=''&summary=''&source='')

But the parameters I pass are never used it always falls back to what is being served directly from the server.

1. Do I have to use the API to make this work and if so can I use the API without making the user authenticate?
2. Is there a correct way to pass this so that linked in will display the  correct data.

Comment: Are you able to resolve this?

Comment: Nope, I had to change my my build process, so I built all the pages locally. It sucks but yeah it only works with server rendered content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this more I realised that the linked ins share URL does not take its parameters it only takes what is served from the server. So I changed my build process not to get the pages in run time but to precompile them onto the server. Maybe in the future linked in will have resolved this for dynamic pages.